# If my home has no footing, how dangerous is it for a contractor to install an indoor drainage system in my basement?

Tags: basement, drainage, footings

I have gotten estimates from some contractors for installing indoor drainage in my basement. They'd be breaking into the concrete floor around the edges of the basement, right next to the basement walls. The basement walls are brick, the home is about a hundred years old. I'm told there's a good chance there is no footing under the walls.

One, but only one, contractor said it would be necessary to pour concrete as they go in order to sort of create on-the-fly footing.

Other contractors did not mention this.

But the guy who did mention it said he thinks his company is the only one that takes this lack of footing into account when doing this kind of work (plausible?) and that it's very important to do so (true?)

So my questions are, is it dangerous and how dangerous is it to install this kind of drainage system in a home without footing, and is it plausible that only one company in Indianapolis actually does anything to alleviate that danger when installing this kind of drainage?

Comment: You're getting a sales-job on the "more than twice as expensive" option based on your prior question. How long has your home managed to stand as built? Are neighboring homes collapsing around you? Hmm....

Comment: See those are my thoughts too. Granted not all these homes are as old as mine. But, though there's some slight bowing in the basement walls, the house has stood firm for a hundred years right?

I am wondering if wisdom here is to grade the yard first, which appears to me to be an under a thousand dollar diy job even for nonexperience diy'ers like me, and just see if I still see moisture in the basement during heavy rains. (I've already replaced teh roof and gutters and downspouted everything away from the house.)

Comment: Fixing the grade is always **job one** unless you are going to dig around the outside for drainage, in which case it's job two and often also three after it settles a year later.

Comment: Grading first.   I wouldn't touch a basement if I knew there were grading issues.    Also adding footers to a building with no issues has the chance to introduce issues.     For older homes we don't touch footers, support beams, any of those things... unless there is good reason to.

Comment: DMoore, after grading etc exterior, if we still see a bit of water in the basement during heavy rain (as we currently do) would you say it is safe to do interior drainage WITHOUT adding footing etc? Or would that be even more dangerous?

Comment: Can you describe the specific problem the proposed indoor drainage is meant to resolve?

Comment: @whatsisname, I was calling around to places because when I bought the home a year ago, the guy I called in to check on foundation stuff said that the horizontal cracks in the basement walls were not a dire emergency but that also within the first few years I should definitely be looking at mitigating or repairing.

When I called people in last week for estimates they said hydrostatic pressure is the first thing I should worry about, and that internal drainage was my most economical choice. 

I am now wondering whether grading and better downspouting will be most of the actual solution.

Comment: Without knowing the specific construction of the old building, the only thing I'll accept is a sump pit with the floor sloped towards it. It sounds like the contractors are suggesting indoor drain lines along the wall, which could introduce additional problems. Suggest asking them to provide you with sketches and post them to clarify the question.

Comment: So, it sounds like there isn't actually a known problem? You are just trying to prevent a hypothetical future problem? Is that correct?

Comment: The difference of a footing? It is needed when the wall is only 6 or 8” thick as concrete needs footing but your walls are much wider so no “footing” is needed the brick is full width so there was no footing or need for one.  adding interior drain tile is a common and good way to create a dry basement if exterior drainage can not be accomplished interior tile cost more because it’s more work to create the perimeter drain or that is what I have seen in the past as the best method but I have not seen any work needed to be done to the wall so I would not believe anything needed to be done.

Comment: @Whatsisname, part of my problem is, I don't know what problems look like, I'm relying on the contractors. What I see is horizontal cracking across most of three walls, and very slight inward bowing, and, when there are heavy rains, what I'd describe as a small amount of water going from a corner of the basement towards the middle floor drain. Do these seem like problems? I honestly don't know! How can I tell?

Comment: @Ed Beal, I think I understand what you're saying but how do you know my walls are thicker than 8"? Is it just because of the age and what you know about how it would have been constructed back then?

Comment: @r13, does a sump pit with floor sloped towards it* help relieve hydrostatic pressure on the walls? (I'm asking from a position of abject ignorance.)

*The floor is already sloped towards the center where there is a drain hole which leads to god knows where.

Comment: No, the sump pit does not help to relieve the hydrostatic pressure on the wall, UNLESS it has a pipe connected to the drain line in the backfill against the wall. I suspect you do have such a connection. Keep an eye on your sump pump, if it turns on and off without surface (floor) water, then it is collecting the groundwater.

Comment: @r13, how might I go about identifying that drain line connection on my own?

Comment: Is there a floor drain in other locations of the basement? If not, keep an eye on the drain pipe for indication of water coming out from it. You may place a small piece of dye, so the water trace will be easily identified. If the pipe is live, then it is potentially connected to a subdrainage system to relieve the hydrostatic pressure and keeping the floor dry.

Comment: If the pipe is dry all the time but there are seepages (water flow) from the walls, then it could have become clogged. BTW, what was the reason that has caused your attention/concern and feels necessary to do something  (what is your objective)?.

Comment: It came to my attention and felt like a concern because when I bought the house a year ago, part of the process involved my having a foundation contractor take a look at the foundation to tell me about any issues he saw. He said the cracking and bowing of the walls was not an urgent issue, but that I should do something to mitigate further cracking/bowing in the next few years. Also I just generally hear that water getting into the basement from outside is bad.

I've never seen sign of water coming out of the central drain pipe (and know of no other drain pipe). What is the implication?

Comment: 3752935, I have remodeled ~20 Victorian homes all that had brick walls none of them had footings and at 100 years old most of them were fine with internal or external drainage added the walls were solid or even thicker for basements all the way down to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of houses that are built on soil that only requires a footing the same thickness as the foundation.  If the footing is the same width as the wall you could technically claim there is no footing.

The width of the footing is based on the load of the house and the bearing capacity of the soil.  Often 100 years ago basements weren't for living in and some moisture and cracks in the foundation were acceptable.

The biggest concern I'd have living in a house like that is radon.  Indiana isn't noted for low radon gas.  The second is going to be moisture.  The third is going to be thermal performance and comfort.

Even if you have the grade outside correct and account for ground water - assuming your basement is never below the ground water table - there are other things to be concerned about.

I've taken 100 year old houses, blown out the slab, underpinned the foundation (adding a footing wider than the wall) while also adding height to the basement, added a powered sump pit, added interior perimeter drain, added drain rock, added slab insulation, added a moisture/radon barrier ( you might also want an active/passive radon mitigation system ), and put back a slab.  As you can imagine it isn't a super cheap option.  Excavating outside and sealing the exterior wall from water and adding a perimeter drain system is typically the preferred approach but if you are already doing the slab work it can be more cost effective to use interior perimeter drain.

What to do depends on budget, how long you plan to keep the house and your usage of the basement.